How to fix wrong number of k-points error in Qantum ESPRESSO while running pw2wannier90.x?
I found this error for running this HSE06 function in QE Wainner90.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     task #         0
     from pw2wannier90 : error #        72
     Wrong number of k-points
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

This is my MoS2.win file. When I run,
pw2wannier90.x < pw2wan.in > pw2wan.out

I face k points error. What can I do?
num_bands = 30
num_wann = 11

num_iter = 20

dis_win_min = -8
dis_win_max = 5
dis_froz_min = -8
dis_froz_max = 3.5

# PLOTTING
bands_plot = .true.

begin kpoint_path
G 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   K 0.3333 0.3333 0.0000
K 0.3333 0.3333 0.0000   M 0.5000 0.0000 0.0000
M 0.5000 0.0000 0.0000   G 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
end kpoint_path

# SYSTEM
begin unit_cell_cart
ang
      3.1840664647       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
     -1.5920332323       2.7574824458       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       0.0000000000      18.1271126464
end unit_cell_cart

begin atoms_frac
Mo 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.5000000000
S  0.3333333333 0.6666666667 0.4217548051
S  0.3333333333 0.6666666667 0.5782450789
end atoms_frac

# PROJECTIONS
guiding_centres = .true.

begin projections
Mo: dxy; dyz; dxz; dx2-y2; dz2
S: px; py; pz
end projections

# KPOINTS
mp_grid = 6 6 2

begin kpoints
    0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
    0.1666667  0.0000000  0.0000000
    0.3333333  0.0000000  0.0000000
    0.5000000  0.0000000  0.0000000
    0.6666667  0.0000000  0.0000000
    0.8333333  0.0000000  0.0000000
    0.0000000  0.1666667  0.0000000
    0.1666667  0.1666667  0.0000000
    0.3333333  0.1666667  0.0000000
    0.5000000  0.1666667  0.0000000
    0.6666667  0.1666667  0.0000000
    0.8333333  0.1666667  0.0000000
    0.0000000  0.3333333  0.0000000
    0.1666667  0.3333333  0.0000000
    0.3333333  0.3333333  0.0000000
    0.5000000  0.3333333  0.0000000
    0.6666667  0.3333333  0.0000000
    0.8333333  0.3333333  0.0000000
    0.0000000  0.5000000  0.0000000
    0.1666667  0.5000000  0.0000000
    0.3333333  0.5000000  0.0000000
    0.5000000  0.5000000  0.0000000
    0.6666667  0.5000000  0.0000000
    0.8333333  0.5000000  0.0000000
    0.0000000  0.6666667  0.0000000
    0.1666667  0.6666667  0.0000000
    0.3333333  0.6666667  0.0000000
    0.5000000  0.6666667  0.0000000
    0.6666667  0.6666667  0.0000000
    0.8333333  0.6666667  0.0000000
    0.0000000  0.8333333  0.0000000
    0.1666667  0.8333333  0.0000000
    0.3333333  0.8333333  0.0000000
    0.5000000  0.8333333  0.0000000
    0.6666667  0.8333333  0.0000000
    0.8333333  0.8333333  0.0000000
    0.0000000  0.0000000  0.5000000
    0.1666667  0.0000000  0.5000000
    0.3333333  0.0000000  0.5000000
    0.5000000  0.0000000  0.5000000
    0.6666667  0.0000000  0.5000000
    0.8333333  0.0000000  0.5000000
    0.0000000  0.1666667  0.5000000
    0.1666667  0.1666667  0.5000000
    0.3333333  0.1666667  0.5000000
    0.5000000  0.1666667  0.5000000
    0.6666667  0.1666667  0.5000000
    0.8333333  0.1666667  0.5000000
    0.0000000  0.3333333  0.5000000
    0.1666667  0.3333333  0.5000000
    0.3333333  0.3333333  0.5000000
    0.5000000  0.3333333  0.5000000
    0.6666667  0.3333333  0.5000000
    0.8333333  0.3333333  0.5000000
    0.0000000  0.5000000  0.5000000
    0.1666667  0.5000000  0.5000000
    0.3333333  0.5000000  0.5000000
    0.5000000  0.5000000  0.5000000
    0.6666667  0.5000000  0.5000000
    0.8333333  0.5000000  0.5000000
    0.0000000  0.6666667  0.5000000
    0.1666667  0.6666667  0.5000000
    0.3333333  0.6666667  0.5000000
    0.5000000  0.6666667  0.5000000
    0.6666667  0.6666667  0.5000000
    0.8333333  0.6666667  0.5000000
    0.0000000  0.8333333  0.5000000
    0.1666667  0.8333333  0.5000000
    0.3333333  0.8333333  0.5000000
    0.5000000  0.8333333  0.5000000
    0.6666667  0.8333333  0.5000000
    0.8333333  0.8333333  0.5000000
end kpoints


Please use code block to show your input file.

This might just be the formatting here, but the k-points need to be on separate lines in the input file.

I know this from working with EPW: apparently for nscf calculations, QE sometimes adds additional k-points to the explicit set you give. I dunno why, I assume some symmetry reasons.
Double check the nscf output from QE and see if the number of k-points is the same as the number you told it to use. If not, the solution is to use calculation = 'bands' in QE instead of nscf. The other steps, e.g. pw2wannier90.x are unchanged.
Let us know if this helps!
Edit: I saw that you posted a separate question about a different issue, but you posted your scf input file there too. Do you also do an nscf calc. before pw2wannier90.x ? Can you post those input files too (scf / nscf), whichever is relevant?
